# How to get page number from the decoded href for a pdf opened in Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf

I opened a pdf document in Firefox, then also opened the bookmarks. If I right click a bookmark and Inspect I can see some href like this

```
file:///D:/Dictionary%20By%20tf%20ur%20man.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A114%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C0%2C766.451613%2Cnull%5D
```

This link is opening the page#106 of the pdf. How I can decode the above url to get the value for the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw it at an online URL encoder/decoder to see how it works

First one I found online - https://www.utilities-online.info/urlencode

Encoded-

```
Dictionary%20By%20tf%20ur%20man.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A114%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C0%2C766.451613%2Cnull%5D
```

Decoded-

```
Dictionary By tf ur man.pdf#[{"num":114,"gen":0},{"name":"XYZ"},0,766.451613,null]
```

That should give you enough info to reverse engineer the format.

Answer (score 1):

The information is urlencoded and says

```
[{"num":114,"gen":0},{"name":"XYZ"},0,766.451613,null]
```

I guess it opens page 114 which is labeled 106 due to the page number count is starting after the title page and table of contents.